# Question about Multi-Tap Transformer

Tags: transformer

So I have this multi-tap transformer as a project. I bought the transformer, the only thing I did is the connections and the casing. When I tried to connect a 12v DC motor, the motor will vibrate like it is spinning but the rod/tip of the motor is not. Sometimes it spins clockwise or counter clockwise. What is the problem? Help please.[image]

Comment: Are you running a DC motor from an AC source?

Comment: Wiring diagram?  DC motors won't work when supplied with AC, or with wrong voltage.

Comment: Oh shoot. I  just realized that I dont know if this transformer converts AC-DC. Nothing on the label. So guys you think this is step down AC-AC? About the wiring im pretty sure its correct.

Comment: That's a pretty case, by the way.

Comment: @rlmarco oh man. A transformer, by the very definition of what a transformer is, is AC/AC...

Comment: you need a rectifier between the transformer and the motor or an ac motor....

Comment: @Marcus Müller you are right I just read that too. I need to know more about electronics I guess, Im just starting here btw. Thank you guys, Im learning :)

Comment: you need something to prevent the power cord from being ripped out .... there should be a knot tied in the power cord on the inside of the case ..... a large cable tie around the power cord would work also

Comment: @Marcus you should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @dim indeed, I should, even if it feels a bit silly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A transformer, by the very definition of what a transformer is, is an AC/AC converter.

So, you can't attach a DC motor directly to a transformer. You need some kind of *rectifier* after the transformer, or you need an AC motor.

Comment: Up-voted so you fell less silly :-)

Comment: don't forget that the peak DC voltage after the rectifier will be √2 times higher than the AC input, you may need to add a voltage regulator or use a lower AC input voltage to run whatever DC device within its specs.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Marcus Muller's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383662/question-about-multi-tap-transformer#answer-383668), you *can* excite a DC motor with an AC signal, but it won't do what you're expecting.  Exciting a mid-range DC motor with mains frequency (50 or 60 Hz) is likely well into the stop band of the motor's frequency response.  This explains why the motor was humming but no motion was observed on the output shaft.